# Generating a new password using each of (A-E) and (0-9) only one time randomly

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you generate a password by randomly mixing 5 letters (A-E) and 10 numbers (0-9) in any order without replacement, producing a 15 character password. If all distinct passwords are equally likely to happen, what is the probability that letter A is adjacent to a number in the password?

How do we account for the fact that someone is chosen only once? When a character is selected form (A-E) (for probability 1/5), does the new probability equal (1/4) since we removed a letter? What's the quickest way to answer questions of this nature?

Answer (score 1):

Your example gets at the gist of the issue. There are $15$ choices for the first character. Since the first character doesn't get reused, there are $14$ choices for the next character, then $13$, etc. Multiplying all these together yields $15!$ total orderings. Another application of this idea is given a fixed point, say in the third location, there are $14*13$ ways to choose the two before it (the fixed character can't be used) and $12$ ways to choose the next one immediately after and $11!$ ways to finish the rest of the password. As a general point, there are $n!$ was to arrange $n$ objects in an ordering.

You can now answer more general questions, like the one in the problem, but it looks like you wanted just this clarified rather than the whole answer so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: So if there are $15!$ ways to arrange these objects in an ordering, how many of these orderings contain $A$ adjacent to a number?

Comment: Can you answer the specific question using these ideas? It doesn't seem clear to me how to apply a fixed position when $A$ can be anywhere in the string.

Comment: You do each location separately and sum them. Each position for $A$ is equally likely.

Comment: How do you account for the fact that $A$ has to be adjacent to a number on either side (and on one side when $A$ is at the ends)?

Comment: Just go through and count how many was do what you are interested in, and divide by the $15!$

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of password that meet the criterion and divide by $15!$ (the total number of passwords).

If A is in the first or last position (2 ways), there are 10 choices for the adjacent number (10 ways), and then we can arrange the other 13 charcters however we want. This is $2\cdot10\cdot13!$ passwords.

If A is in the middle 13 positions, it can have either one or two numbers adjacent.

If it has one number adjacent: Pick the position for A (13 ways), pick if the number is on the left or right of A (2 ways), what the number is (10 ways), and which letter is on the other side of A (4 ways). Then we can arrange the other 12 characters however we want. This is $13\cdot2\cdot10\cdot4\cdot12!$.

If A has two numbers adjacent: Pick the position for A (13 ways), pick the number on the left of A (10 ways), pick the number on the right of A (9 ways). Then we can arrange the other 12 characters however we want. This is $13\cdot10\cdot9\cdot12!$.

Therefore the total number of passwords where A is next to a number is $2\cdot10\cdot13! + 13\cdot2\cdot10\cdot4\cdot12! + 13\cdot10\cdot9\cdot12!$. When you divide by $15!$ you get $0.90476..$ so roughly $90\%$ of all password are of this form.

Comment: Why is there 9 ways to pick a letter on the other side of A in your 4th paragraph?

Comment: My mistake, I wrote my answer as if there were 10 letters and 5 numbers. I changed it so it is correct now. The reason why it is 4 (and was 9) is because you have already used the letter A.